# Can I get a specific order of fields on Eleasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I requested like :

```
{
  "_source" :{
   "fields2",
   "fields3",
   "fields1"
  }
}
```

Expected response looks like :

```
{ - 
   "_source": { - 
      "field2": "data2",
      "field3": "data3",
      "field1": "data1",
   }
}
```

But the response I've got looks like:

```
{ - 
   "_source": { - 
      "field1": "data1",
      "field2": "data2",
      "field3": "data3",
   }
}
```

Can I custom a specific order on Eleasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You cant get _source value in specific order. The source document is a plain old JSON object as define [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Please read [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/17640#issuecomment-209037691) comment on github issue which will give you more understanding of why it is not possible.